# insert into mysql is not working

Tags: java, mysql

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection dbaTo = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ourDB1", "root", "");

    PreparedStatement stat2 = dbaTo.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tblEntry");
    journEnt = journCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();

    String sqlbebe = "INSERT INTO tblJournEnt(strEntJournCode, strEntJournType) VALUES (?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement stat3 = dbaTo.prepareStatement(sqlbebe);
    ResultSet resultaNgSet = stat2.executeQuery();

    if(resultaNgSet.next()) {
    do{ 
        kuhaEntCode = resultaNgSet.getString(1);    
        substring2 = kuhaEntCode.substring(Math.max(kuhaEntCode.length() - 3, 0));

    }while(resultaNgSet.next());
        } //IF////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    else{
        stringsaEnt = "Ent000";         
    }

    int convertToInt2 = Integer.parseInt(substring2);
    int addition2 = convertToInt2 + 1;

    if (addition2 >= 10) {
        String prd = "ent0"; 
        stringsaEnt = prd + addition2;
    }
    else {
        String prd2 = "ent00";
        stringsaEnt = prd2 + addition2; 
        //pasaEnt(stringsaEnt);

    }



    stat3.setString(1, stringsaEnt);
    stat3.setString(2, journEnt);
    stat3.addBatch();
    stat3.executeBatch();
    stat3.close();

}catch(Exception saiko) {

}
```

This is my code and i don't know but it won't insert into my database

Comment: Always, always, always, always, always, always, always, always, always, always, always, always, always, always, always, always, always, always close your `Connection` in a `finally` block

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing the two parameters for `stat3` / `sqlbebe`.

Also, having it all wrapped in a try block with empty catch doesn't help, this leads to any exceptions being silently ignored. Print / log / rethrow the error and you'll see why your SQL statement failed.